# Can't pass an argument to the spider class

Tags: python, scrapy

When I call this script using `script crawl myspider -a t=2` the argument refuse to get passed to the `total` argument that is declared in the class myspider.

```
class myspider(Spider):
    name='myspider'
    total=1
    def __init__(self, t=1, *args, **kwargs):
        Spider.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.total = t
    print(str(total))
# Prints 1 despite argument passed being 2
```

Any idea why I can't pass an argument to a variable declared in the mother class ?

Comment: please fix the indentation on your code

Comment: The `print` call is class-definition level code; when the class is defined, `total=1`

Comment: If you want to see what `total` is when the class is **instantiated**, add a `print` call **inside** the `__init__` definition.

Comment: @jmetz I tried to simplify the code to make it more straight forward to answer but what I really need to do is to pass `total` and other arguments to another method that yields a generator for `start_urls`  to use. How can I pass the value of total to another method in the mother class `myspider` or to an attribute ?

Comment: don't use `start_urls`, use [`start_requests`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests)